# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined Angular 2

Tags: angular, build

I am not able to get the value of 'Username' in form data in an angular 4 app. In html I have this lines.

```
                  <section class="mdc-card__primary">
                        <div class="mdc-text-field">
                            <input type="text" id="username" class="mdc-text-field__input"
                            name="username" [(ngModel)]="loginValue.username" aria-controls="username-helptext">
                            <!-- <label for="username" class="mdc-text-field__label">Username</label> -->
                            <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdc-text-field">
                            <input type="passsword" id="password" class="mdc-text-field__input" 
                            name="password" [(ngModel)]="loginValue.password" aria-controls="password-helptext">
                            <!-- <label for="password" class="mdc-text-field__label">Password</label> -->
                            <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mdc-text-field">
                            <input type="hidden" id="ltype" class="mdc-text-field__input" 
                            name="ltype" [(ngModel)]="loginValue.ltype" value="site">
                            <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
                        </div>
                  </section>
```

in Logincomponents.ts I have this lines

```
        export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


          loginValue:any;

          resnonseValue:any;
          cookieValue:any;
          errorMsg:any;
          sessionValue =  localStorage.getItem("userSession");
```

Now I got the below error after building the project.

```
          main.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

Because of this my form data is empty .

1) when I declare it as string, it gives me compile time error that 'username' does not exist on type string. same is for password and ltype.

2) I tried with exporting interface but it is not working, the same error is there

3) I tried with https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html index signature

4) with ng-serve in development mode there is not errors or warning but when building , after a successful build this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your **loginValue**  in component like below, so that you will not get that error:

loginValue:any = {};

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `loginValue` before you use 2 way binding:

```
loginValue = {
    username : '',
    password : '',
    ltype : ''
}
```

Or you should remove 2 way binding and do it like

```
[ngModel]="loginValue?.username"
```